# Error inmatrix : Non-numeric matrix Extent

Tags: r, matrix, bioconductor

I was trying to run GSA(Gene Set enrichment Analysis) function in R using the Biobase package: Expression Set.
I was using the resp.type to be "Two class unpaired" .But when i run the function  :

```
gsa <- GSA(x=exprs(Eset), genesets=genesets, genenames=genenames, y = as.integer(factor), resp.type= "Two class unpaired", minsize=2,maxsize=500,nperms=500)
```

It gives me an error saying :

```
Error in matrix(1, nrow = n, ncol = 1) : non-numeric matrix extent
```

I dont know what this error means.I did `mode(exprs(eset))`,it gives me "numeric"

Can anybody tell me how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: It looks like `n` does not evaluate to a numeric value. (Try `n <- "a"
;  matrix(1, nrow=n, ncol=1)` to see why that's my guess.)